# Добавить ID переключателя в href по клику

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добавляю в href ИД переключателя по клику, но при каждом нажатии на переключатель, ИД добавляется снова и снова, а нужно только один, попробовал очистить href при нажатии, не срабатывает.
Подскажите как правильно реализовать?

```js
jQuery(document).on('click', '.radio', function() {
  var $link = jQuery('#link'),
     href = $link.attr('href').replace(/^(.+)\?.+$/, '$1');
     $link.attr('href', href + '-' + $(this).attr("id"));
     console.log( $link.attr('href'));
  
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="row-flex radio-input">
<div><input id="casco" class="radio" name="gender" type="radio" /><label for="casco">Obre viva (casco)</label></div>
<div><input id="costado" class="radio" name="gender" type="radio" /><label for="costado">Obre muerta (costado)</label></div>
</form>
<a id="link" class="boton-ir-p my-btn bgr" href="velero-quilla-corrida"> Siguente</a>
```

Comment: вы лучше в дата-атрибут радио впишите нужную ссылку и ее подставляйте целиком в href.

Comment: вместо `on` попробуйте `.once`

Comment: Ой.. теперь это [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) называется :facepalm:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как я сделал, после загрузки страницы в переменную храню значение `href`-a, а потом каждый раз добавляю в текущий `href` переменную плюс `id` `radio` кнопки.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="row-flex radio-input">
<div><input id="casco" class="radio" name="gender" type="radio" /><label for="casco">Obre viva (casco)</label></div>
<div><input id="costado" class="radio" name="gender" type="radio" /><label for="costado">Obre muerta (costado)</label></div>
</form>
<a id="link" class="boton-ir-p my-btn bgr" href="velero-quilla-corrida"> Siguente</a>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        
//        После загрузки в переменную храним атрибут href
        var link_href = jQuery('#link').attr('href');
        jQuery(document).on('click', '.radio', function() {
            var $link = jQuery('#link'),
            $link.attr('href', link_href + '-' + $(this).attr("id"));
            console.log( $link.attr('href'));

        });
    });
    
    
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

На первый клик запоминаем первоначальный атрибут `href` в `data-href` и используем его:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.radio', function() {
  var $link = jQuery('#link');
  var href = $link.data('href');
  if (!href) {
    href = $link.attr('href');
    $link.data('href', href);
  }
  $link.attr('href', href + '-' + $(this).attr("id"));
  console.log($link.attr('href'));
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="row-flex radio-input">
  <div><input id="casco" class="radio" name="gender" type="radio" /><label for="casco">Obre viva (casco)</label></div>
  <div><input id="costado" class="radio" name="gender" type="radio" /><label for="costado">Obre muerta (costado)</label></div>
</form>
<a id="link" class="boton-ir-p my-btn bgr" href="velero-quilla-corrida"> Siguente</a>
```

Comment: не проще сразу в дата-атрибут инпута полную ссылку вписать нужную?

Comment: @teran возможно, проще. Хотелось свести изменения кода вопроса к минимуму.